# invalid initialization of reference of type for class WholeNumbers

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, operators, definition

I am trying to write out a class called WholeNumber. I am not finished writing it, I like to try to compile frequently so I can keep the errors low and manageable. When I go to compile the class as it is I get this error:

fibonacci.cpp: In member function ‘std::__cxx11::list& WholeNumber::operator=(WholeNumber&)’:
fibonacci.cpp:41:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::list&’ from expression of type ‘WholeNumber’
       return *this;

I've tried looking up the error to see if I could find the answers to my problem, but I could only find that you can't initialize a non-const reference from a const reference. I don't understand what that could be referring to my code. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fibonacci.h"   // for fibonacci() prototype                                                                                                     
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class WholeNumber
{
private:
   list <int>  digits;

public:
   //default constructor                                                                        
   WholeNumber() { }
   //non-default constructor                                                                    
   WholeNumber(unsigned int number) {number = 0;}
   //copy constructor                                                                           
   WholeNumber(const WholeNumber & rhs) { }
   //destructor                                                                                 
   ~WholeNumber() { }


   friend ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const list <int> * l);
   istream &  operator >> (istream & in);
    WholeNumber & operator +=(const WholeNumber & rhs);

   list <int> & operator = (WholeNumber & rhs)
   {
      this->digits = rhs.digits;
      return *this;
   }

};
```

Comment: `SomeClass::operator=` usually returns `SomeClass&`. Why does yours attempt to return a reference to an unrelated type? In any case, the type of expression in `return` statement doesn't match the declared return type of the function.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is the pseudo-code I was given: + assign (rhs : WholeNumber) : list. So that's how I interpreted it. Do you think it should be written differently? @ Igor Tandetnik

Comment: Well, you can have `operator=` return `list&` if you are so inclined, though this would be highly unusual. Or, you could instead have a member function literally named `assign` - that would seem to match the pseudocode more closely, if you intend to interpret it literally. Either way, your `return` statement should be modified to actually return an object of type `list`, and not `WholeNumber`.

Comment: I see what you are saying @Igor Tandetnik. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @Megan You do realize that the user-defined assignment operator is totally unnecessary for your class?  The compiler's default version is perfectly fine and works correctly without having to override it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no I am just a student trying to learn a language. So are you saying I don't need the function to get the class to work? because with out it, I seem to have other errors. though I sure thats probably my fault as well.

Comment: @Megan One of the fundamentals of C++ is what the compiler gives you for free when you write a class.  You get for free a copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor.  The times when you want to override these functions is if you are managing a resource within the class, such as dynamically allocated memory.  If you are not managing a resource (and you're not), then the compiler's default version of these functions work perfectly fine without intervention.  By overriding these functions for no reason, you are at risk of introducing bugs for no reason.

Comment: oh okay. thanks @PaulMackenzie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned type of the copy assignment operator is `list <int> &`

```
   list <int> & operator = (WholeNumber & rhs)
   {
      this->digits = rhs.digits;
      return *this;
   }
```

but an object of the type `WholeNumber` (`*this`) is returned and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.

Maybe you mean the following

```
   WholeNumber & operator = ( const WholeNumber & rhs )
   {
      this->digits = rhs.digits;
      return *this;
   }
```

Also these operators

```
   friend ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const list <int> * l);
   istream &  operator >> (istream & in);
```

are invalid. For example the first operator should be declared like

```
   friend ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const WholeNumber & );
```

And the second operator also should be a friend function like

```
   friend istream &  operator >> ( istream & in, WholeNumber & );
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is the pseudo-code I was given:                                       + assign (rhs : WholeNumber) : list.  So that's how I interpreted it. Do you think it should be written differently? @vlad from Moscow

Comment: @Megan I am sure. In this case you can write like obj1 = obj2 = obj3;

Comment: do you mean like this: this->digits= WholeNumber digits = rhs.digits?

Comment: @Megan Yes, I am sure.